# Unable to insert data in sqllite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written contentvalues for insertion, code compiles fine but data is not getting inserted in the database. My problem here is that, tables are getting created but data is not getting inserted, I have no clue.

My code goes like this:
It has 2 classes first class has database connection information and second class has table creation and data insertion statements.

```
Class 2:
create table and insert method that has content values and I am returning the value to main class
class 1:
database connection and database open command.
```

Can anyone please guide as I am new to android and trying to learn on my own.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Post your code and logcat..

Comment: refer [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/03/sqlite-database.html) tutorial or [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/03/sqlite-databases-with-external-db.html) if you using external db.

Answer (score 0):

here two classes one create database connection and other class insert a user (using user class object) in the database

```
public class UserDataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public UserDataHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    database.execSQL(UserMataData.sql);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

above class create database

```
public class UserDataSource {

private SQLiteDatabase userDataBase;
private UserDataHelper userDataHelper;


public UserDataSource(Context context) {
    super();
    userDataHelper = new UserDataHelper(context, UserMataData.DataBaseName, null, UserMataData.DataBaseVersion);        
}

public void openDataBase()
{       
    userDataBase = userDataHelper.getReadableDatabase();
}

public void closeDataBase()
{
    userDataHelper.close();
}
public boolean addUser (User user)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(UserMataData.Name, user.getName());
    cv.put(UserMataData.University, user.getUniversity());

    long insert = userDataBase.insert(UserMataData.TableName, null, cv);
    if( insert != -1)
        return true;

    return false;

}

public Cursor getAllUsers()
{
    return userDataBase.query(UserMataData.TableName, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

}

note user object is just a object of User class you can simply replace it by any other stuff you want to add in the database AND change ContentValues accordingly

Comment: Thanks Haider for your reply....Geralt_Encore and Meghs I can post code but can't post logcat as logcat is not generated.. this is where I am getting confused on how to trace... Is there any solution for this

Comment: @siva you can trace errors in logcat follow these steps if your logcat tab does not appear
1- window
2-Show View
3-others (on clicking a window will appear)
4-type logcat in bar
log cat will appear on right vertical bar or depend on you settings

Comment: public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public database (Context context,String name,CursorFactory factory,int version) {
super(context, name, factory, version);
}
t1 t;
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
database.getwritabledatabase();
database.execSQL(t.table1);
database.insert(t.tablename,null,t.insertdata())
}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0,int arg1,int arg2) {
}
public class t1 {
String table1="Create table"
public contentvalues insert(){
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(column1.getID());
cv.put(column2.getname());
return cv;
}
}
}

Comment: Thanks Haider... I went through all tabs but log cat is totally empty... when I created table it was visible but when I added insert statement data is not inserted and logcat is also empty.

Comment: @siva send my you email i can send you a android project which enlighten you great fully

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Superb Tutorial...It's Help u a lot...The link is [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: Hello Siva Log should be generated ..Restart your Eclipse and run the project again..

Comment: Thanks for you response Nandu... will android emulator and logcat performance depends on system OS as emulator in my machine will always gives me problem and some times doesn't open at all after restarting several times it works.... I am really sick of this android emulator which will waste most my time.. Is there any solution